# Google Script - Call APi - Error object

Tags: javascript, api, google-apps-script

I'm doing a URL call in a API but I've got this error

> TypeError: Cannot find function getContentText in object

Here is bellow my code.
I even tried to encode the URL but still not working.
Could you please tell me where I'm wrong ? And what is the fix ?

Thank you,

```js
  var url = 'https://welcome.de.coremetrics.com/analyticswebapp/api/1.0/report-data/explore/explore.ftlid=634022';  
  var params = {
    'clientId': 'mi_id',
    'format': 'JSON',
    'userAuthKey' : 'my_key',
    'language' : 'en_US',
    'viewID' : 'default.ftl',
    'period_a' : 'D20170601',
    'fileName' : 'explore_explore^id=634022_default_view_D20170601.json'
  }
   var options = {
   'method' : 'GET',
   'payload' : params
 };
 
   response = UrlFetchApp.getRequest(url,options);
  var data = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
```

Comment: At ``UrlFetchApp.getRequest()``, there is no  ``getContentText()``. You can directly see ``response``. So you can use ``Logger.log(response)``. If you want to do ``fetch``, please change ``UrlFetchApp.getRequest()`` to ``UrlFetchApp.fetch()``. In the case of ``UrlFetchApp.fetch()``, ``getContentText()`` can be used for the response. The detail information is https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#methods

Comment: Thank you for this ! It works !

Comment: Welcome. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution found:

```
  res = encodeURI(query)
  response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(res, {muteHttpExceptions: true, escaping: false}).getContentText();
```